# JS change img src with real link for lazy load

Tags: javascript, image

I have following js function to load the image only when in view by changing the src attribute.

```
 <img src="" r_src="/myimage.png" />

 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        jQuery('img[r_src]').each(function(i){
          var rh = jQuery(this);
          if(rh.position().top > (jQuery(window).scrollTop()+jQuery(window).height())){
                rh.attr('src', rh.attr('r_src'));
                rh.removeAttr('r_src'); 
              }
        });
    })
```

It's not working as I expected.

Images are shown at the top of the page and I am not sure if that is the reason why the code doesn't work.

What change should I make ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below logic may help:

```
<img src="" r_src="/myimage.png" />

 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        jQuery('img[r_src]').each(function(i){
          var rh = jQuery(this);
          if(rh.position().top < (jQuery(window).scrollTop())){
                rh.attr('src', rh.attr('r_src'));
                rh.removeAttr('r_src'); 
              }
        });
    })
```

I believe, no need to check window height. Just check current scroll position from top and image top position. If it(Image top position) is less than current scroll just load the image.

Hope this helps you to crack the logic.

Comment: I was testing out the code, and I am realizing that the `jQuery(window).scroll(function(){` does not even get triggered. I tried `window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {` and still not triggered (I tested with `alert("does it work?")`). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This can do the trick `$(document).on('scroll',function(){ // your all code inside });`